# CSS Animation shorthand

Tags: animation, css, webkit, opacity

Can you please help me to understand this shorthanded line:

```
.instructions div { -webkit-animation:"instructions-opacity" 2s 1s forwards; }
```

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#the-animation-shorthand-property-

`animation_root_element { [-prefix-]animation: "animation_name" duration delay direction; }`